# After dispatching to update content change UI

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my react-native app, in the controller I have :

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
return {
  dispatch,
  editProfile: bindActionCreators(editProfileRequest, dispatch)   
};

}
```

The connect function :

```
return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
 provideHooks({ fetch: fetchProfile })(WrappedAccountController),
 )
```

Once this has been successful, the server returns the object with the updated values.
I want to set a isSuccessful variable to true, that I can use to change some things in the UI. Like displaying that the field has been successfuly updated.
Is it in the mapDispatchtoProps where I need to do that ?
I am very new to react native so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would check for the change from your API call in a lifecycle method.

#### Lifecycle listener

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.value) {
      this.setState({ doSomething: true });
    }
  }
```

#### Render method

```
          render() {
            return (
              <div>
               { this.state.doSomething ?
                <p>
                  Did something!
                </p> : null
               }
              </div>
            );
          }
```